# Which version of Android supports AES/GCM/NoPadding encryption?

Tags: android, encryption, android-security

Getting crash on Moto G (Android KitKat) if trying to access AES/GCM/NoPadding cipher.

```
GCMParameterSpec gcmParameterSpec = new GCMParameterSpec(16 * 8, iv);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, gcmParameterSpec);
```

Is it only supported on Andorid M and higher?

Is there any way to use it on lower Android versions?

Comment: The only way is if you pack it into your own binaries with your app.

Comment: Alexey did you find how to use it on versions below M?